# Switch Vagrant to use Parallels instead of VirtualBox

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant

Is it possible to use Parallels instead of (insane slow) VirtualBox in Vagrant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it's not Parallels (which you may have already paid for), there is a plugin for using VMWare Fusion:

http://www.vagrantup.com/vmware

The plugin is *not* free, so you'll need to buy licenses for both the plugin and Fusion.

I get a kernel panic in my VM a few times a week. According to Mitchell, VirtualBox has had kernel panic issues on Macs for years that have never been well resolved, and swapping to Fusion is the best alternative.

Comment: Thank you! This is absolutely fantastic! I have Parallels but everything is better then Oracle VM, so I'm going to by Fusion right away.

Comment: @WojciechBednarski could you share what is your expirience now on Mac OS X + VMWare Fusion + Vagrant? I am now using vagran with free VirtualBox on OS X and sometimes it is very unstable.

Comment: @Gabe will it be easy to cooperate on same project with other collegeus using vagrant + virtualbox on Linux, when I start using vagrant + vmware fusion?

Comment: @andi Fantastic, for example compilation time inside VM dropped from about 10min to 2min - same project same hardware. There is however some issue introduced in VMware Fusion 6.0.2 with sharing folders and some people have issue with it.

Comment: @WojciechBednarski dzięki! so would you suggest to stay by fusion version 5?

Comment: @andi or use 6.0 or 6.0.1

Comment: @andi I believe each provider has a different "box" file format, so you would have to build separate VMs for VirtualBox and VMware.

Answer (score 15):

Maybe this will help you (fresh and new)

https://github.com/yshahin/vagrant-parallels

Answer (score 4):

Finally there is an official Vagrant Provider from and for Parallels! Unfortunately it's not mentioned on [www.vagrantup.com](http://www.vagrantup.com).

See [Paralles' Vagrant Documentation](http://parallels.github.io/vagrant-parallels/) and the [Parallels GitHub page](https://github.com/Parallels/vagrant-parallels/) of the Vagrant provider project. For further questions about the provider there is a [dedicated official forum](http://forum.parallels.com/forumdisplay.php?737-Parallels-Provider-for-Vagrant).

<s>As of now there is just one limitation: "The Parallels provider supports all basic Vagrant features, except the next: "Forwarded ports" configuration is not available yet." (taken from [the readme on GitHub](https://github.com/Parallels/vagrant-parallels#features))</s>

Thank you, [AgentK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868/agentk), for pointing out that that "Forwarded ports" are available as of Parallels 10 for Mac.

Comment: @AgentK: I incorporated your editing suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There was a large commit a few month ago, that merged the *machine-abstraction* branch:

- https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/commit/391dc392675c73518ebf04252d824fe916e8860b

which was even [discussed a bit on Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4406467).

> This branch brings in the "machine abstraction" code. This is a major
>   milestone in the development of Vagrant as it abstracts all of the
>   VirtualBox-specific code out into a plugin.

The gotcha:

> White it is technically possible now to write plugins for other
>   providers, there is still major work to be done to make this feasible.

And as of now, the only provider in *master* is virtualbox:

- https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/plugins/providers

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use Parallels with Vagrant. Here's a line by line set of instructions to do so (assumes you have Parallels and Vagrant installed).

1. `$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-parallels`
2. `$ mkdir some-project/ && cd some-project`
3. `$ vagrant init parallels/ubuntu-14.04`
4. `$ vagrant up --provider parallels`

Note, you only have to install `vagrant-parallels` once. Also note, you only have to pass in `--provider parallels` the first time you `up`, after that it will automatically use the parallels provider.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can use Vagrant **only** with subscription based Pro or Business versions. Not with regular perpetually licensed Home version unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

found this thread in google along with official Parallels-Vagrant integration: https://github.com/Parallels/vagrant-parallels